# Django 2.2 В БД не сохраняются комментарии

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Django 2.2 Python 3.6
После заполнения формы, комментарий прилетает в django, но не сохраняется в БД... Модели постов и комментариев в одном приложении. Ни каких трейсбэков не получаю. Не понимаю что и где я проглядел...

**Views.py**

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_comment_form = NewCommentForm(request.POST, instance=post)

        if 'add_comment' in request.POST and new_comment_form.is_valid():
            comment = new_comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.content = request.POST.get('content')
            comment.active = True
            comment.save()
    else:
        new_comment_form = NewCommentForm()

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'new_comment_form': new_comment_form,
    }
    template = 'content/post_detail.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class NewCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = (
            'content',
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        comment = super(NewCommentForm, self).save(commit=False)
        comment.content = self.cleaned_data['content']

        if commit:
            comment.save()
        return comment
```

**Models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='post_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Комментарии')
    author = models.ForeignKey(VertexUser, related_name='comment_author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
    content = models.TextField('Содержание', blank=True)
    like = models.PositiveIntegerField('Лайки', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    dislike = models.PositiveIntegerField('Дизлайки', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации', auto_now=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField('Опубликовано', default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Автор {self.author} | Опубликовано {self.publication_date}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: `'add_comment' in request.POST` это что?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 Это я разбираю request.POST что бы узнать какой инпут нажал пользователь. Но проблему я уже решил ))) instance=post была лишней, сразу не заметил...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> new_comment_form = NewCommentForm(request.POST, instance=post)

Привязка в post была лишняя.